# Removing the blur part from the view

Tags: ios, objective-c

[image: Little Blur inside the selected part in red]

I have this view created with the gradient, but there happens to be blur part coming, i am totally clueless how to remove it.

Here is my code:

```
NSArray *grandientColor = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                           (id) [[UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:0.79 alpha:1] CGColor],
                           (id) [[UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:0.93 blue:0.61 alpha:1] CGColor],
                           (id) [[UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:0.85 blue:0.43 alpha:1] CGColor],
                           (id) [[UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:0.7 blue:0.25 alpha:1] CGColor],
                           (id) [[UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:0.55 blue:0.18 alpha:1] CGColor],
                           (id) [[UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:0.3 blue:0.1 alpha:1] CGColor],
                           (id) [[UIColor colorWithRed:0.9 green:0.08 blue:0.04 alpha:1] CGColor],
                           (id) [[UIColor colorWithRed:0.75 green:0 blue:0.13 alpha:1] CGColor],
                           (id) [[UIColor colorWithRed:0.51 green:0 blue:0.14 alpha:1] CGColor],
                           (id) [[UIColor colorWithRed:0.29 green:0 blue:0.08 alpha:1] CGColor],nil
                           ];

UIView *viewGradient = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15.0f, 50.0f, 126.0f, 25.0f)];

viewGradient.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
viewGradient.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
viewGradient.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
viewGradient.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;

CAGradientLayer *maskLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
maskLayer.opacity = 0.8;
maskLayer.colors = grandientColor;

// Hoizontal - commenting these two lines will make the gradient veritcal
maskLayer.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.5);
maskLayer.endPoint = CGPointMake(1.0, 0.5);

maskLayer.bounds = viewGradient.bounds;
maskLayer.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;
[viewGradient.layer addSublayer:maskLayer];
[legendView addSubview:viewGradient];
```

Please help me out with this.

Thank is advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually happening on both sides, but it's more pronounced on the left because of the lighter colour of the gradient. The reason it happens is because of antialiasing artefacts on the rounded corner; the border is drawn on top of the gradient, so the gradient kind of leaks behind the border on the wrong side when the partially-drawn border pixels are added.

The easiest way to fix it in your case is to make the gradient layer slightly smaller than its parent one. So instead of matching the bounds, you can do:

```
// maskLayer.bounds = viewGradient.bounds;
maskLayer.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;
maskLayer.frame = CGRectInset(viewGradient.bounds, 1, 1);
maskLayer.cornerRadius = 4;
```

You'll need to also move the line setting the anchorPoint above where you set the frame, and apply a corner radius, as in the above code.

This produces the desired effect:

[image: Desired effect]

If we make the border partially transparent, you can see what's happening:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are talking about cornerRadius not blur?
What to you mean exactly?
You have opacity 0.8 it gives transparent
Remove this:

```
viewGradient.layer.cornerRadius = 5; // rounds your view
maskLayer.opacity = 0.8; // make your view transparent
```

Comment: answer from robert worked well for me, but thanks for your effort. :-)